# Using absolute path to command

Tags: sh, posix

I'm writing a command which uses the environment variable `CC`. If `CC` is set, my command makes a system call to `$CC`, otherwise `cc` is used. When invoking `cc`, should I use `/usr/bin/cc` or simply `cc`? Can I even rely on `cc` existing in `/usr/bin`? Since a user can set `CC` to any string I think using the path to `cc` provides no extra safety.

Comment: Depends on where the `cc` is located in your `PATH` variable. By default it is in `/usr/bin/cc`, but for some reason if one customizes it by appending a path `/new/path/cc` before `$PATH`, then the shell recognizes the first one. So if you are absolutely sure no one would have modified `PATH` variable, and on a POSIX system `/usr/bin/cc` should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cc` is not part of the POSIX standard, so you cannot assume any particular location for it. (Really, the same is true for *any* command; that is what `PATH` is for.) Your script has one documented requirement, which is that it be able to run some command to compile code.

1. By default, that command is `cc`.
2. You can modify `PATH` to influence which `cc` gets used.
3. You can set `CC` to be more specific; it can be another command name, a relative path, or an absolute path.

Note that `CC` and `PATH` are not mutually exclusive. If `CC` is set to an absolute path, that will be used. If you just use something like `CC=gcc`, then the value of `PATH` can still determine which of several installed versions of `gcc` are used.